This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct). -- after app comes from background
The scenario is I want to forcefully put the user to appUpdatePage whenever the user comes from the background and check if the update is available with the Backend API call.
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
     //after async call and condition check
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => AppUpdatePage(),
          ));
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }


We don't have much context there, but usually you must check if current context is still mounted after an async call. To do so, check if context.mounted is true. This part is to avoid the crash caused by an unmounted context.
Now, to be able to use the Navigator without a mounted context (which seems to be your case), you could use a GlobalKey to make it accessible from anywhere. I don't think it is the best solution (probably should your logic be changed somehow), but it should work:
navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
   MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => AppUpdatePage(),
   )
);


print(navigatorKey.currentState); //null

Okay, it was a silly mistake, I was assigning globalKey to the wrong parameter(key instead of navigatorKey)- my bad.
